# SQLite3 - Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new to SQL, so maybe this is a newbie question. But here is my simple code(also, I am using python):

```
@classmethod
def next_page(cls):
    cls.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Id < 10 ORDER BY Date DESC Limit 10")
    rows = cls.cur.fetchall()

    return rows
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "database.py", line 20, in next_page
        rows = cls.cur.fetchall()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied
```

Any one know what the deal with this is? Any help is appreciated

Comment: The error and the SQL shown do now match. Your SQL uses *0* bindings.

Comment: Your error message also contains typos. Can you please copy and paste the *full* traceback of the exception instead?

Comment: I would consider it bad form to have a column named Date.  It's likely to be a SQL keyword at worst, and it's not descriptive at best.  Is that the SENT_DATE?  RECEIVED_DATE?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I realize the SQL has no bindings, that's why it makes no sense. I can assure you that is the exact SQL I am using(It's inside a function, but that doesn't matter).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also I pasted the full traceback

Comment: @TehEpicPineapple: Yet the code in your traceback does not match what you pasted.

Comment: Sure you've got the right query?  Maybe the error goes with another one....

Comment: @MartijnPieters Look, this is the code. *All* of it.

Comment: @duffymo What exactly does that mean. Sorry, I am very new to datbase. Do you am I sure this is the code that is being run?

Comment: You got an error.  The message doesn't appear to match the SQL query you've posted, so I'm wondering if there's another query in your code that is triggering it.

Comment: It is *theoretically* possible that the exception is thrown at the wrong moment; if there is a bug in the C extension that somewhere did not check for an error condition, then a later error condition test (in, say, `.fetchall()`) would show the earlier unhandled exception.

Comment: Nope. I am running this from a REPL, so there's no code that is getting triggered I don't know about

Comment: However, since the `sqlite3` module is part of the Python distribution and is thus much more widely tested, the most likely explanation is that you are not running code that you think is running. Insert a few more print statements into that function to test that that is indeed the SQL that is being executed and try to provoke the exception again.

Comment: @TehEpicPineapple: If you are running this from the REPL, did you import that method or did you enter the whole class into the REPL first?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I imported `database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out(since I was running the code in the REPL) that you have to CTRL+C and enter the REPL again when you modify a file.

Comment: Or you can use `reload(database)`.